# PHP/MySQL - Updating an SQL table with data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a worker shift monitoring/accounting system I've built, there is an option to delete Staff Members. This works fine but I would like to archive shifts for staff members who are deleted.

I looked into it and it seemed the best way to do this would be to update my shift table, before the delete, into another table. I looked up how to do this via another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11410316/3169285) however I'm getting an error: `fatal error call to member function on a non-object`.

Based on what I can find, this error is caused when you try to pass a null value, which has left me confused as the value I'm trying to pass is a GET and is working fine when I test it.

```
$sql = "
  UPDATE table_archive
     SET table_shift.shift_date = table_archive.shift_date,
         table_shift.start_time = table_archive.start_time,
         table_shift.end_time = table_archive.end_time,
         table_shift.total_hours = table_archive.total_hours,
         table_shift.rate_of_pay = table_archive.rate_of_pay,
         table_shift.uniqueid = table_archive.uniqueid, 
         table_shift.addedBy = table_archive.addedBy,
         table_shift.paidRate = table_archive.paidRate,
         table_shift.totalPaid = table_archive.totalPaid
    FROM table_shift, table_archive
   WHERE table_shift.uniqueid = ?
";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$deleteid = htmlentities($_GET['id']);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $deleteid);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm stuck as to why this wont pass, the GET cant be a null value as the test delete I'm using at the moment passes the same variable and works fine. `mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE FROM table_staff WHERE uniqueid='$deleteid'")`

It may be that I'm using the SQL code wrongly or there is some silly thing I've forgotten but this has me stumped. Failing to fix this code, any other suggestions as to how to achieve the intended function are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't UPDATE FROM. Your syntax is wrong.

Instead, use this:

`INSERT INTO table_archive

 SELECT * FROM table_shift WHERE table_shift.uniqueid = ?`

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect this, however still getting the error :  Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: The change you made in the code breaks the syntax of MySQLi, '?' is the placeholder and the 's' just sets the statement to expect a string. The error must lie within the $sql variable as simply changing the sql variable to "DELETE FROM table_staff WHERE uniqueid = ?" works fine

Comment: @danielsmile Yes, sorry, that was an incorrect fix. From the original error, either $connection isn't an object or $stmt isn't when you're calling `bind_param`. Use var_dump to find out which it is.

Comment: add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` :)

Comment: @Ben will give it a shot now

Comment: @Ben Still gives fatal error call to member function on a non-object, very confusing but atleast can narrow down the problem to the SQL. http://pastebin.com/WzqF0gL6, the top code gives the error, bottom code working fine.

Comment: That's not where the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE goes. I would wonder if that's the issue though. You can test by changing the INSERT to INSERT IGNORE and use the same SQL as I posted above. This sql should work... try hardcoding in the id instead of using the ? to see if that makes a difference (also, comment out the bind)

Comment: @Askanison4 Good suggestion with the hardcoding the id, your code works fine if i hardcode it. So the problem is with the id, which is even more confusing as if you see the pastebin from my previous comment, it works fine in the second SQL statement.

Comment: @danielsmile make sure that you specify which table you want to do the where uniqueid on: `WHERE table_shift.uniqueid` otherwise it will be ambiguous

Comment: @Askanison4 Found the problem, thank you for your help and persistance :)

Comment: @danielsmile could you post the solution? And mark an answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the use of bindParam correct?

If you use a `?` it should look like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE column_name = ?

$sth->bindParam(1, $value_in_php, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

If it's not `?` but `:param_name` use this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE column_name = :param

$sth->bindParam(':param', $value_in_php, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Your error sounds not like an SQL error, but a PHP error.

And if you want to update the `table_archive` table the SQL doesn't look correct. It should imho be like this:

```
UPDATE table_archive
   SET table_archive.shift_date        = table_shift.shift_date
     , to_table_that_should_be_updated = from_table_with_value_to_update
  FROM table_shift
 WHERE table_shift.uniqueid = ?
```

Comment: I use MYSQLi not PDO, the usage is correct as I use this in many other areas of the site. See here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40467/system-for-inputting-and-monitoring-worker-shifts

Comment: Okay. Than it's not a format problem. I guess you have no object/resource?